# Show/hide section based on dropdown -js

Tags: javascript, html

Hi all I got my code all nice and pretty but the problem is that it is a bit buggy. When you select the field that actually un-hides a section and then another one that hides it- the "hidden" section is still there for some time!
Below you will see my code on codepen:http://codepen.io/Nestalna/details/qpjsy

Javascript:

```
function show(aval) {
    if (aval == "1") {
        optionyes.style.visibility='visible';
        optionyes.style.display='block';
        Form.fileURL.focus();
    } 
    if (aval == "0") {
        optionyes.style.visibility='hidden';
        optionyes.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
            <label id="title" for="degree">Which degree are you interested in? </label><br />

                <select id="degree" name="degree" onchange="java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" >
                    <option selected="selected" value="Please select one"> Please select one </option>
                    <option value="0" > Concurrent Enrolment </option>
                    <option value="1" > 2015 Applied Bioethics Summer Study </option>
                    <option value="2"> Non Degree (9 hours or less) </option>
                </select>
        </div>      

        <div id="optionyes" style="visibility:hidden" >You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here </div>
```

Comment: Double-check your link to codepen.io - it returns a 404 for me.

Comment: Sorry, try: http://codepen.io/Nestalna/details/qpjsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select '2' it doesn't hide at all. You only want to show it if aval==1 right? So change `if (aval == "0") {` to `else {`

```
function show(aval) {    
    if (aval == "1") {//if 1 then show it
        optionyes.style.visibility='visible';
        optionyes.style.display='block';
        Form.fileURL.focus();
    } 
    else {//for everything else hide it
        optionyes.style.visibility='hidden';
        optionyes.style.display='none';
    }    
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywcqf

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much! I gotta get trained up on java some more. I just started learning it yesterday. Thank you @Moob !

Comment: No worries - you're welcome. http://www.codecademy.com/ is a decent place to start learning. (Psst: its "Javascript" not "Java" - they're two different languages ;) )